# Dump rows of a CSV file which contain a sequence of blank fields

Tags: python

I am trying to write a python program to clean survey data coming from a CSV file.
I would like to dump rows which contain a sequence of blank fields, like the first and the third line in the following example.

```
"1","a","b","c",,,,,
"2","a","b","c","d","e","f",,"h"
"3","a","b","c",,,,,
"4","a","z","u","d","i","f","x","h"
"5","d","c","c",,"c","f","g","z"
```

Following my unsuccessful code:

```
import csv

fname = raw_input("Enter input file name: ")
if len(fname) < 1 : fname = "survey.csv"

foutput = raw_input("Enter output file name: ")
if len(foutput) < 1 : foutput = "output_"+fname


input = open(fname, 'rb')
output = open(foutput, 'wb')


searchFor = 5*['']

writer = csv.writer(output)

for row in csv.reader(input):
    if searchFor not in row :
        writer.writerow(row)

input.close()
output.close()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about

```
# change this to whatever a blank item is from the csv reader
# probably "" or None
blank_item = None

for row in csv.reader(input):
    # filter out all blank elements
    blanks = [x for x in row if x == blank_item]
    if len(blanks) < 5:
        writer.writerow(row)
```

This will count the number of blanks in a row and let you drop them as desired.

Comment: I had to convert row first to a string to make it work. Nevertheless with this method the blank fields have not been identified. `print blanks` returns an empty string.

Comment: blanks will be empty, it's a list of all the blank items in the row. These are then counted for the filtering.

Answer (score 1):

Use `counter` to check if one list is subset of another as below. If you want to remove empty elements then just use `None`, `bool`  or `len`to filter blanks and discard them-

```
import csv
from itertools import repeat
from collections import Counter
input = open(fname, 'rb')
output = open(foutput, 'wb')

writer = csv.writer(output)
#Helper function
def counterSubset(list1, list2):
    c1, c2 = Counter(list1), Counter(list2)
    for k, n in c1.items():
        if n > c2[k]:
            return False
    return True
for row in csv.reader(input):
    if not counterSubset(list(repeat('',5)),row):# i used 5 for five '' you can change it
        writer.writerow(row)#use filter(None,row) or filter(bool,row) or filter(len,row) to remove empty elements
input.close()
output.close()
```

Output-

```
1,a,b,c,,
2,a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h
4,a,,z,u,d,i,f,x,h
5,d,c,c,d,c,f,g,z
```

Comment: This would filters blanks but not the line containing them. I am looking for a solution where for this example only row 2, 4, and 5 are written

Comment: I am looking for a solution which works for a sequence of blanks, as in the survey data valid rows can also contain some blank fields. I edited my example which wasn't laid out  clear enough.